# Rod cutting "in higher dimensions"

Tags: optimization, dynamic, dimension

I might be using the wrong terms here and there but bear with me...

I know that the original rod cutting problem has a runtime of n^2 through dynamic programming, which is what I'm currently learning. My question is outside of the curriculum.

However, **what happens if the problem is to maximize value gained from sections of an object of higher dimensions? Even more than 3?**

**If D is the number of dimensions, does time complexity become n^(1+D), when used to solve rod cutting problems of higher dimensions?**

I have worked on a problem where the problem was maximizing values gained from unlimited cuts of given dimensions, from a given *area*. E.g. [2x3], [1x4] cuts from a [5x5] area. These cuts have different values assigned to them.

The problem of finding which cuts are worth using, is something I actually bothered finding (what I believe to be is) an O(n) algorithm for, but wasn't worth implementing, because even the 1-dimensional rod cutting problem has n^2 complexity. Also, unless the given amount of cuts and the cuts and values themselves were dumb (as in some never being worth using), it would be unnecessary.

On my own, I found that there is no way to get any lower runtime bound than n^3, because I am forced to check for possible sections in two dimensions. And the cuts can be flipped (they remain in consideration as long as they do not go outside of the given area).

By using the given area's dimensions, one can produce a grid of optimized solutions for the given cuts, which will increase as one travels further from the grid's origin (0,0), but only when the cuts can occupy the area up to that point.

I am forced again to check by comparisons across the whole grid but within the previous for loop, because it is now iteration over a grid. However, these comparisons are done across the height and width of the grid *separately*, resulting in n runtime, within 2 `for` loops. And it does indeed look like a total of n^3 in terms of runtime.

Just a small matter of academic interest.

Comment: There is a _Theoretical Computer Science_ Stack Exchange where experts who study just this could answer your question.